# Update Wordpress Theme System

Tags: plugins, theme-development

i'm creating a premium Wordpress theme and i was wondering if there's a wordpress plugin or system that allows for easy upgrades of future theme updates for possible clients. Something like the internal system that Wordpress uses for its open source themes.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I was researching this yesterday, and found [this script](http://clark-technet.com/2010/12/wordpress-self-hosted-plugin-update-api) , based on [this](http://konstruktors.com/blog/wordpress/2538-automatic-updates-for-plugins-and-themes-hosted-outside-wordpress-extend/)

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The update library for themes is now available. You can find it [here](http://w-shadow.com/blog/2011/06/02/automatic-updates-for-commercial-themes/)

**Edite:**
It seems that this library has been deprecated. And they refer to [Plugin Update Checker](https://github.com/YahnisElsts/plugin-update-checker/).
Thank you @Buttered_Toast

Comment: Welcome to wpse! From the link you pasted, *Update 2017-06-20: This library has been deprecated*, seems like its out of date. Seems like they refere to [Plugin Update Checker](https://github.com/YahnisElsts/plugin-update-checker/)

Comment: Thanks for the notice :D